# Passing a width to an embedded sending request?

Tags: docusignapi

I am working on implementing docusign embedded sending.  It will run in a frameset within our site.  It is currently a little bit wider than the width of our main frame, leading to the document links on the right hand side being cut off.

Is there a way to pass in a width?  I'd like to avoid resizing the frames for just this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to specify width of the embedded DocuSign viewing/sending/signing session -- DocuSign controls the width of its content, in order to ensure that it will adequately render the viewing/sending/signing user interface.

Additionally -- best practice would be to launch the DocuSign URL in a new browser window, rather than embedding it within an iFrame.  Two primary reasons for this:

1) The DocuSign UI is best rendered in a full screen where it can utilize all screen real estate (rather than being confined to a smaller portion of the screen in an iFrame) -- this is especially important for usability on mobile devices.

2) Some browsers have issues when an app rendered/embedded in an iFrame (in this case, DocuSign) attempts to utilize cookies.